# Can Vaishnavas worship other Gods(anya devata)?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, vaishnavism, demi-god

Generally Vaishnavas don't worship Gods other Sri Vishnu and His incarnations(Swaminarayan Sampradaya being a notable exception).Is there any mention in scriptures if the worship of anya devata is permitted in Vaishnavism or not?

Comment: Yes, anya devata worship is permitted, as long as it is kept in mind that anya devatas are subordinate to Vishnu, who alone is the supreme brahman according to Vaishnavism.

Comment: Can you mention sources preferably from Vaishnava scriptures?

Comment: @Rishx Heard from vaishnava friends and also know from experience. I am not very knowledgeable in vaishnava scriptures.